# Openfire fastpath chat causing site to load slowly

Tags: asp.net, javascript, loading, openfire

We are adding openfire fastpath chat to our site.  It will determine and indicate when live chat is available or not and display an appropriate image to indicate the current status and links for each state.

The javascript call hit's a function that is on another box and this function uses document.write to output the html to the page.  I know there is a delay because it is making the request to another server and waiting for a result to be returned.  The pause here is about a half second, but causes the rest of the page load to be held up.

Has anyone experience a similar issue or offer any tips for getting this to load synchronously somehow.  I tried putting this into an aspx ajax panel, but that seemed to cause other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used an iframe that is the only thing I could find that seemed to work.